# Second post loop duplicates the same post

Tags: php, wordpress

I've read multiple questions about multiple loops repeating the same post and even though I've tried the suggested answers I can't seem to work out why my second loop repeats the same post.

The initial loop is fine and ideally I'd need to keep the HTML structure for design purposes, but I just can't figure out why my second loop will repeat the same post.

```
<div class="latest-post-feed">
    <?php
       global $post;
       $blog = array( 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'offset' => '7');
       $blogPosts = get_posts( $blog );
    ?>
       <div class="post-list row">
          <div class="post-column column-left">
             <?php $i = 1; foreach ( $blogPosts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                <?php if($i == 2): // splits it out into 1 x 2 column ?>
                  </div><!-- .column -->
                  <div class="post-column column-middle">
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($i == 4): // splits it out into 1 x 1 column ?>
                   </div><!-- .column -->
                   <div class="post-column column-right">
                <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-latest', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
             </div><!-- .post-column -->
          </div><!-- .post-list -->
       <?php wp_reset_postdata();  wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div><!-- .latest-post-feed -->

  <div class="latest-post-feed">
     <?php
       global $_post;
       $_blog = array( 'posts_per_page' => '7', 'offset' => '-1' );
       $_blogPosts = get_posts( $_blog );
     ?>
       <div class="post-list row">
         <div class="post-column column-left-bottom">
           <?php $x = 1; foreach ( $_blogPosts as $_post ) : setup_postdata( $_post ); ?>
             <?php if($x == 2): // splits it out into 3 x 3 column ?>
                </div><!-- .column -->

                <div class="post-column column-right-bottom">
             <?php endif; ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-latest-2', get_post_format() ); ?>
           <?php $x++; endforeach; ?>
         </div>
       </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();  wp_reset_query(); ?>
 </div>
```

And the output is always:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzcCi.png

What I'm trying to do is create a second loop which continues from the offset off the first loop. So ideally there's 11 posts that need to be shown in total, the first loop would show 4 and the second loop would show 7, following in a numerical order from the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry not enough time to make it with your code, but maybe this will help you (this is how i do it on my theme):
**Loop 1:**

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); $images = '0'; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $images++; $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
    <div class="carousel-item <?php if($images == '1'){ echo 'active';} ?>">
        <div class="gradient"></div>
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-tobi">Artikel lesen</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

**Loop 2:**

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array('offset' => 3));

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  $title = get_the_title();?>

<div class="card border-dark">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large', array( 'class' => 'card-img-top', 'alt' => $title  ) ); ?>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted"><?php _e( 'Kategorie:' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?><br>Gepostet am: <?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></small>
        </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p class="sry"><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, dazu habe ich wohl noch nichts geschrieben.' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @raju_eww have you fixed it?

Comment: I've just implemented your solution and with a few little tweaks it worked perfectly. Thanks again for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="latest-post-feed">
    <?php
       global $post;
       $blog = array( 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'offset' => '7');
       $blogPosts = get_posts( $blog );
    ?>
       <div class="post-list row">
          <div class="post-column column-left">
             <?php $i = 1; foreach ( $blogPosts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
**$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;** ?>
                <?php if($i == 2): // splits it out into 1 x 2 column ?>
                  </div><!-- .column -->
                  <div class="post-column column-middle">
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($i == 4): // splits it out into 1 x 1 column ?>
                   </div><!-- .column -->
                   <div class="post-column column-right">
                <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-latest', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
             </div><!-- .post-column -->
          </div><!-- .post-list -->
       <?php wp_reset_postdata();  wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div><!-- .latest-post-feed -->

  <div class="latest-post-feed">
     <?php
       global $_post;
       $_blog = array( 'posts_per_page' => '7', 'offset' => '-1' );
       $_blogPosts = get_posts( $_blog );
     ?>
       <div class="post-list row">
         <div class="post-column column-left-bottom">
           <?php $x = 1; foreach ( $_blogPosts as $_post ) : setup_postdata( $_post );
 **if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;** ?>
             <?php if($x == 2): // splits it out into 3 x 3 column ?>
                </div><!-- .column -->

                <div class="post-column column-right-bottom">
             <?php endif; ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-latest-2', get_post_format() ); ?>
           <?php $x++; endforeach; ?>
         </div>
       </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();  wp_reset_query(); ?>
 </div>
```

Add $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; after first loop of foreach then add if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; after second loop of foreach.

Comment: Hi thanks for this tip, but this doesn't work. The same posts aren't appearing in both loops, its just the second loop duplicating the same post 7 times.

Comment: Add 'posts_per_page' => '-1' instead of 'posts_per_page' => '7' and remove 'offset' => '-1' from second loop.

Comment: Remember in my code there is **$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;** and  **if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;** so please remove all **

Comment: The posts_per_page => -1 gives undesired results, as stated I need there to only be 7 posts in the second loop as it keeps with the design (please see the screenshot in original question). The variable for do_not_duplicate and the check for the duplicate posts in the second loop still makes no difference. There is not duplicate posts between both loops, it is just 1 post duplicating 7 times in the second loop. See screenshot: https://image.ibb.co/dqiJUS/loopduplicate.png